# Динамическое изменение размеров Label на форме WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Динамическое изменение размеров Label на форме WPF при изменении шрифта, размера шрифта и текста.

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: @maxwell кхм, изначально когда кидаешь на форму label у него есть исходный width и height допустим 150 и 50. Но когда меняешь шрифт то текст уже не помещается и обрезается. Так вот как в WPF это исправить и подогнать размер Label под размер текста. В винформс знаю как сделать, а вот тут загвоздочка.

Comment: Ну так дайте вашему Label большой размер. Текст будет покрывать лишь сколько надо.

Comment: @VladD ну неужели я бы задавал такой вопрос если бы не было именно необходимости четко подогнать размер.

Comment: @VladimirH: Окей, тогда опишите вашу задачу полнее. Возможно, она решается [не так, как вы предполагаете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/10105).

Comment: @VladD Окей опишу полностью ЕЩЁ раз, имеется программа написанная на WPF в лейблах отображается информация. При всём этом, лэйблы расположены на прозрачной форме. Если задавать больший размер то это будет мешать доступу к элементам расположенным под прозрачной частью лейбла ![пример](https://pp.vk.me/c636629/v636629595/4765d/K_7oDJfvkHU.jpg) учитывая что 2016 это лейбл, вот именно его width перекрывает доступ к файлу "video"

Comment: @VladD И естественно я понимаю что можно ещё поиграться с прозрачностью и т.д. но интересует именно подгон размера компонента под имеющийся в нём текст с выбранным шрифтом и размером. В винформ есть решение, а в WPF так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В WPF определение точных длин не нужно, за вас, в отличие от WinForms, работу выполняет layout manager.

Вот такой код:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Name="Target" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="2016"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO09a.png" Height="40"/>
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center">Video</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

при динамическом изменении размера метки даёт вот такой результат:

[image: анимашка]

Comment: ярлык "Video" находиться под прозрачной формой а именно на рабочем столе. "2016" это лейбл на прозрачной форме которая и перекрывает доступ к ярылку. @VladD

Comment: @VladimirH: Окей, тогда опишите, пожалуйста, точнее, чего именно вы хотите. Вы написали в комментарии, что вам нужно подогнать размер Label под размер текста, ну так именно это в ответе и есть. Напишите подробнее постановку задачи. (И если можно, прямо в вопросе, там есть кнопка «править».)

Comment: @VladimirH: Как вы видите, в примере ширина Label в точности равна ширине текста внутри (ну и плюс padding).

Comment: @ VladD у меня сейчас информационный шок. Просто убрал Width и Height в коде и всё пошло замечательно. Но всё таки неужели в WPF нет возможности подсчитать размеры занимаемые текстом с определённым шрифтом и надо подрубать в using winforms O_o

Comment: @VladimirH: [Можно](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9266288/276994), но это практически никогда не нужно. Layout manager умеет всё намного лучше.

Comment: и не по сабжу, а можно ли сделать компоненты чтобы они были как бы прозрачным слоем. Чтобы можно было кликать через них?

Comment: @VladimirH: Layout manager умеет всё намного лучше. Если писать код как в WinForms и делать layout руками, тогда такая функциональность может пригодиться. Но лучше без этого.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50349/discussion-between-vladimir-h-and-vladd).

Comment: @VladimirH: Да, конечно. IsHitTestVisible, кажется.